# Frontend performance wise, is it better to combine tw bootstrap and font awesome into existing files or call them from cdn

Tags: performance, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

2 best practices for performance frontend collide :

For example here : https://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html

- Minimize HTTP Requests
  So if we follow this practice, we will combine all css and js file into one file, even for vendors ones, and maybe put them on a cdn, but even we won't benefit from a popular url/cached resources.
- Use a Content Delivery Network
  So we will pull tw bootstrap, font awesome (and other libraries I use like jquery) from popular cdn like this one http://www.bootstrapcdn.com or google ones, but we will make multiple http requests.

For popular frontend css/js, we cannot follow both rules.

In that case, which rule should we follow in priority ?

Answer (score 0):

If many websites are linked to the same CDN, the multiple http requests won't affect the site's performance as much since the visitor's browser will most probably have cached the CDN when it visited another site using the same CDN so it doesn't have to load it again.

The advantages of using CDN over lesser http requests include:

```
-Decrease server load
-Faster content delivery
-100 percent availability
-Increase in the number of concurrent users
-More control of asset delivery
```

So, assuming the CDN is "popular" and heavily linked, then yes, it can lead to a better site performance as compared to merging your styles and/or scripts together for lesser http requests.